# Spark 1.5 Elementwise Product

Tags: pyspark

*Spark 1.5* recently came out and has element wise multiplication in python (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-feature-extraction.html).

I have no problem applying the *weighting/transforming* vector (v2 in my code below) on a Vector to produce a vector.  However when I try to apply it on RDD[Vector], I get:

> TypeError: Cannot convert type < type 'numpy.float64'> into Vector.

Here's my code:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.mllib.feature import ElementwiseProduct

v1 = sc.parallelize(Vectors.dense([2.0, 2.0, 2.0]))
v2 = Vectors.dense([0.0, 1.0, 2.0])

transformer = ElementwiseProduct(v2)
transformedData = transformer.transform(v1)
print transformedData.collect()
```

How do I produce an RDD[Vector] that is the Hadamard product of v1 and v2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I need to turn v1 into a row Matrix

```
mat = RowMatrix(v1)
```

so for instance:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import RowMatrix

v1 = sc.parallelize([[2.0, 2.0, 2.0], [3.0, 3.0, 3.0]])
mat = RowMatrix(v1)
v2 = Vectors.dense([0.0, 1.0, 2.0])

transformer = ElementwiseProduct(v2)
transformedData = transformer.transform(mat.rows)
print transformedData.collect()
```

will print:
[DenseVector([0.0, 2.0, 4.0]), DenseVector([0.0, 3.0, 6.0])]

What I really need though is a function that will allow v2 to also have multiple vectors, instead of a single vector matrix, but so far that doesn't seem to exist.